# Setting a string in scala when empty

Tags: scala

I need to fix some Scala code, where a dummy-email should be generated, when the actual email is "empty".

So  far it looks like this:

```
val maybeEmail = (response.json \ "email").asOpt[String].map(_.toLowerCase)

User(maybeEmail, ...) // User(email: Option[String], ....)
```

Now, I want to reset "maybeEmail" to: "@dummy-email.com", when it is empty.

This seems to be very trivial, but I had a couple of shots already and couldn't get it to work. 
So far I was trying things like (which were not working):

```
maybeEmail.getOrElse[String](someId.concat("@dummy-email.com"))
```

So please support me on this. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? (be specific: show the exception / compilation error / undesired result)

Comment: well. I tried multiple solutions, all ending up in exceptions like:[error]  found   : java.io.Serializable
[error]  required: Option[String] or similar

Comment: Are you using playframework and playjson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, but let's try this little answer, perhap's it will help you.

If you want a string as result, with a default value, you can do something like this :

```
val optMail = Some("real@real.org")
val mail = optMail getOrElse "dummy@dummy.org"
```

If you want an Option in result instead of a string :

```
val optMail2 = Some("real@real.org")
val mail2 = optMail2 orElse Some("dummy@dummy.org")
```

It seems that what you want is the second case. Your code will be like that :

```
val maybeEmail = (response.json \ "email").asOpt[String].map(_.toLowerCase) orElse Some(someId.concat("@dummy-email.com"))
User(maybeEmail, ...) // User(email: Option[String], ....)
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me! Cheers!